# Smart Phone based Obstacle detection for visually impaired persons using Opencv4Android

Tags: opencv, android, opticalflow

I am working on my semester project. I want to make exactly the same thing as in this video.
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4hA36nXRjw&feature=youtu.be .
I want to make a obstacle detection application in Android using OpenCV. I am unable to calculate the optical flow (By using function `Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`) of the keypoints which I get from *FeatureDetector* Function. Further more I can't refine the points through RANSAC algorithm. I am in very much trouble. Kindly help me if anyone can. I shall be highly thankful to you.

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {

```
private static final String    TAG = "ziadkhan.optical_flow";

public static final int        VIEW_MODE_KLT_TRACKER=0;
public static final int        VIEW_MODE_OPTICAL_FLOW=1;

private int                    mViewMode;
private Mat                    mRgba;
private Mat                    mGray;
private Mat                    mIntermediateMat;
private Mat                    mPrevGray;
private CameraBridgeViewBase   mOpenCvCameraView;

MatOfPoint2f                   prevFeatures, nextFeatures;
MatOfPoint                     features;
private MatOfByte              status;
private MatOfFloat             err;
private MenuItem               mItemPreviewOpticalFlow, mItemPreviewKLT;

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch(status){
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG,"OpenCV Loaded Successfully");
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            }
        }
    }
};
//private JavaCameraView mOpenCvCameraView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    mItemPreviewKLT = menu.add("KLT Tracker");
    mItemPreviewOpticalFlow = menu.add("Optical Flow");
    return true;
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item == mItemPreviewOpticalFlow) {
        mViewMode = VIEW_MODE_OPTICAL_FLOW;
        resetVars();
    }
    else if (item == mItemPreviewKLT){
        mViewMode = VIEW_MODE_KLT_TRACKER;
        resetVars();
    }

    return true;
}

private void resetVars() {
    mPrevGray = new Mat (mGray.rows(), mGray.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    features = new MatOfPoint();
    prevFeatures = new MatOfPoint2f();
    nextFeatures = new MatOfPoint2f();
    status = new MatOfByte();
    err = new MatOfFloat();
}

public void onDestroy(){
   super.onDestroy();
    if(mOpenCvCameraView != null){
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC4);
    mIntermediateMat = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC4);
    mGray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8SC1);
    resetVars();
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mRgba.release();
    mGray.release();
    mIntermediateMat.release();
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();
    final int viewmode = mViewMode;
    switch (viewmode) {
        case VIEW_MODE_OPTICAL_FLOW:

            if (features.toArray().length == 0) {
                int rowStep = 50, colStep = 100;
                int nRows = mGray.rows()/rowStep, nCols = mGray.cols()/colStep;

                Point points[] = new Point[nRows * nCols];
                for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++) {
                        points[i * nCols + j] = new Point(j * colStep, i * rowStep);
                    }
                }
                features.fromArray(points);
                prevFeatures.fromList(features.toList());
                mPrevGray = mGray.clone();
                break;
            }
            nextFeatures.fromArray(prevFeatures.toArray());
            Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(mPrevGray, mGray, prevFeatures, nextFeatures, status, err);
            List<Point> prevList = features.toList(),
                    nextList = nextFeatures.toList();
            Scalar color = new Scalar(255);
            for (int i = 0; i < prevList.size(); i++) {
                Imgproc.line(mGray, prevList.get(i), nextList.get(i), color);
            }
            mPrevGray = mGray.clone();
            break;
        default:
            mViewMode = VIEW_MODE_OPTICAL_FLOW;
            break;
     }
    return mGray;
    }
}`
```

Comment: It won't be easy. https://xkcd.com/1425/

Comment: Then what should i do?

Comment: Have a conversation with your professor or instructor. Talk about what you're thinking of doing, and ask how you should proceed.

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! We're glad to have you here. You should take the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Then feel free to post  if you have a specific programming question that hasn't been asked before on the site.

Comment: How far along are you in the project? Is there specific code that is causing the problem?

Comment: Thankx Sir. By the way i am working on this project for last 5 months but i am not successful. I am really worried coz its my Final Year Project and my Degree completion is pending on this project.

Comment: Sir i have added the video on my youtube channel and also i pasted the link above. Kindly see that Video. Thats exactly what i want to make.

Comment: Yes. A specific problem is that i want to convert the keypoints extracted through function "Featuredetector" are of type MATOFPOINT and i want to caonvert them to MATOFPOINT2F as to calculate the optical flow it requires MATOFPOINT2F.

Comment: This question might help: [OpenCV4Android conversion from MatOfKeyPoint to MatOfPoint2f](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14346482/3345375)

Comment: I have folllowed this link but could not understand properly how to code it. I am not successful so far. I have done so much research but not successful.

Comment: Sir kindly see this video. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4hA36nXRjw&feature=youtu.be  
I actually want to make exactly same application like this.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14402326/3345375) links to another page,  http://www.answers.opencv.org/question/6206/opencv4android-conversion-from-matofkeypoint-to-matofpoint2f/ (although a Stack Overflow answer is really supposed to include the actual solution, and link-only answers are discouraged).

Comment: can we chat in private Sir? I want to send you my code so that if you can understand my problem easily.

Comment: If you have code then please do include it in the question itself -- that's often the most important part of the question. You can create a code block in your post by indenting text four spaces.

Comment: (And I should mention that I personally don't know anything about Android development. I'm just one of the people who volunteers to review new Stack Overflow questions.)

Comment: Actually i am following a book "Mastering OpenCV Android Application Programming". I learnt from there Optical flow and also i run the code present in that book that worked absolutely fine. But in that example the author take points on screen rather than passing the MatOfkeypoints extracted through FeatureDetector Fucntion.

Comment: I am really gratefull to you that u replied and helped me. I am really thankful to you Sir.

Comment: You're very welcome! And please feel free to post on Stack Overflow if you have a specific question about the code you are working with.

Comment: Best of luck to you on your project!

Comment: Thankx Sir. I will post my questions on Stack Overflow if i had any problem. Thankx